# Extract text from embedded tweets with Python & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract separately text from embedded tweets on a webpage. The code below works ok but I need to get rid of start and end lines like these: `Skip Twitter post by...` and `End Twitter post by...`, date and `Report` leaving only tweets. I cannot even see where these lines come from and which tag to use. Will really appreciate your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-44496876')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
article_soup = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'social-embed'})]
tweets = '\n'.join(article_soup)
print(tweets)
```

Comment: please note that sometimes the tweets does not appear with your example. When they do appear check answer and it will give you only tweets like you expected to get - it was hard to find due to the issues with that specific page. @aviss

Comment: yes, I noticed that indeed. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-44496876')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
article_soup = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all('p', {'dir': 'ltr'})]
tweets = '\n'.join(article_soup)
print(tweets)
```

If you also want to get the author of the tweets it's a bit tricky since you don't have a tag for the author. So I used a python code to remove all the tags in between the author like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-44496876')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
articles_soup = [s for s in soup.find_all('blockquote', {'class': 'twitter-tweet'})]
tweets = []
for article_soup in articles_soup:
    tweet = article_soup.find('p').get_text()
    # The last <a href='...'></a> is the date, others are part of the tweet
    date = article_soup.find_all('a')[-1].get_text()
    tweet_author = article_soup.get_text()[len(tweet):-len(date)].strip()
    tweets.append((tweet_author, tweet))
print(tweets)
```

**Note1**: if you want to get only parts of the `tweet_author` you can easily take the tuple first element and tweek it to get the object that you want.

**Note2**: the question code example does not always return tweets, the issue is with the html page since from time to time several elements do not return. The fast solution is to run the `requests.get` method once more - I suggest you look into this issue. 
Once I got the tweets with the original question, I found the tags and I got the tweets that you expected to get, each tweet in a different line in my code.

Comment: It works, when tweets are loaded. But I still cannot fund the tag 'ltr'. Could you explain where I should look?

Comment: Yes, so the problem is, usually, that not all DOM elements have been loaded. It's the same issue that you have in your original answer and why you are sometimes seeing the tweets and sometimes you do not. In that case you cannot use `requests.get()`, instead you need to use `Selenium` package and `wait` for the page to load, check this out: http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/ @aviss

Comment: Yeah, I used `Selenium` in the past but now it is deprecated. I'll have to look for an alternative.

Comment: I noticed that the extracted text is missing the name of a person who tweeted it. It comes after the 'ltr' tag but is not tagged itself. Is it possible to include it? This is an example: <div class="twitter-wrap">
                 <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
                  <p dir="ltr" lang="en">
                   Active shooter 888 Bestgate please help us
                  </p>
                  — Anthony Messenger (@amesscapgaz)
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/amesscapgaz/status/1012406073704239105?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">

Comment: @aviss check my edited reply, it was hard to do since there are no tags but it works.

Comment: thank you so much! Re: Note 2 - I tried to use Selenium but it behaves in the same way as `requests`. I don't quite understand what causes the issue. The page just doesn't load and waiting doesn't help. I opened a separate question here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51214853/5967886 - but haven't received any useful suggestions so far...

Comment: I saw the question, smart that you've opened a new one for that. You probably need a FrontEnd developer to assist with this one, it's not really my expertise.