# Scrape embedded tweets from a webpage with Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract tweets embedded in text articles. The problem with the pages I'm testing is that they load tweets in ~5 out of 10 runs. So I need to use Selenium to wait for the page to load but I cannot make it work. I followed steps from their official website:

```
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-44648563'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/ME/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
tweets_soup = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all('p', {'dir': 'ltr'})]
tweets = '\n'.join(tweets_soup)
print(tweets)
```

I cannot use the option to wait for a certain element to appear because I'm scanning different pages and not all of them have embedded tweets. So to check if Selenium actually works or not I run the above script together with the script which doesn't use Selenium and compare their results:

```
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-44648563'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
tweets_soup = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all('p', {'dir': 'ltr'})]
tweets = '\n'.join(tweets_soup)
print(tweets)
```

I will really appreciate the help of this wonderful community!

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you are using Selenium. All the tweets are available in the page source, and hence can be scraped using `requests`.

Comment: I explained it in my question. `request` works in 50% of my cases. Sometimes tweets are available in the page source, sometimes not.

Comment: @aviss in that case why use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use after. The challenge is to load the page so you can extract what you need by any other means. If you have any suggestions how to do that i'd be happy to try.

Comment: The issue is correct, when using requests sometimes the tweets don't return since the html is not complete, some objects are missing. Seems like several DOM elements are loaded later on so if you have a slow connection it works. Moving to implicite wait should have worked, no idea how to resolve it. I can only confirm that I see the same problem that you raised on my local machine.

Comment: @Oran, thank you for your comment. Yes, I tried using the option of waiting for ALL the elements to load, but it didn't work. Apparently, the problem is not with waiting long enough, the problem is that in these instances the page is never loaded completely...